# Script access to a Single Sign on enabled Service via PingFederate

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, pingfederate

Is it possible to authenticate to a SSO - Identity provider (PingFederate) via code. I am trying to reach a service (API) which previously used HTTP Basic auth to authenticate requests.

Since the service was put behind a SSO, the applications now use OAuth for accessing it which works fine for a browser enabled application.

However, I am trying to make it work for a simple script which has to authenticate via code to PingFederate. Is this even possible?

I am very new to this form of authenticate so please bear with me if my question is very noobish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is very possible - typically whatever can be done in the browser can be scripted somehow, or there are features in PingFederate designed for retrieve an OAuth token without browser interaction altogether if that's your ultimate goal.

For example you could use OAuth resource owner password credentials grant to simply pass a user's username & password to the token endpoint and get it back.  See: https://support.pingidentity.com/s/document-item?bundleId=pingfederate-93&topicId=lzn1564003025072.html

But it's not clear to me from your description what the exact requirements are.  Please reach out to us (Ping Identity - my employer), and our support team would be happy to work through all the details with you: https://support.pingidentity.com/